# Submitting Applications to apache spark 2.3 via REST API

Tags: rest, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, cluster-computing

I have a standalone cluster with 3 machines (1 worker node in each machine), using `PySpark`. The Python script I'm running is a simple transformation that reads from `Oracle` and writes to `MongoDB`.

The DataFrames are partitioned on read and write to better use parallelization and multiple connections.

When I submit my `.py` script via `/bin/spark-submit`, in the Spark UI (HOST:8080) I can see it is handled as an application (app-NNNNNNNNNNNN-IP-NNNN). It's shown in the "Running Applications" section of the UI, I can see the work being distributed in the worker nodes, the total amount of RAM and CORES correctly distributed. In Oracle sessions I can see the multiple connections from all 3 workers IPs working fine, in MongoDB as well. All works Fine as it is expected.

Now I'm trying to do the same but with remote submissions, and using the REST API  "http://HOST:6066/v1/submissions/create". But in this case, the submission is being handled as a Driver (Driver-NNNNNNNNNNNNN-NNNN) and runs on one worker only (the worker node in which the driver runs varies on submissions). In the UI of the master it falls on the "Running Drivers" section.

Is there a way to submit as an application via REST API, or all submissions are treated as an Driver?

This is the command that works fine when I run on the server itself:

```
./spark-submit --master  spark://host:7077 --executor-memory 10G --total-executor-cores 20 path-to-my-py-script/my-py-script.py
```

This is the message I'm sending to the REST API ( http://host:6066/v1/submissions/create)

```
{
    "action": "CreateSubmissionRequest",
    "appArgs": [
        "path-to-my-py-script/my-py-script.py"
    ],
    "appResource": "path-to-my-py-script/my-py-script.py",
    "clientSparkVersion": "2.3.0",
    "environmentVariables": {
        "SPARK_ENV_LOADED": "1"
    },
    "mainClass": "org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit",
    "sparkProperties": {
        "spark.executor.memory": "4G",
        "spark.executor.cores": "10",
        "spark.driver.supervise": "true",
        "spark.ui.enabled": "true",
        "spark.eventLog.enabled": "true",
        "spark.submit.deployMode": "cluster",
        "spark.app.name": "RemoteSubmitTest",
        "spark.master": "spark://host:7077"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can try using Apache livy -
[Apache livy explaination](https://hortonworks.com/blog/livy-a-rest-interface-for-apache-spark/)

If not comfortable with incubating project livy then other option is Spark Job Server -
[Spark Job Server](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver)

Comment: I was hoping to be able to use the default REST API, but i'll take a look at those projects. Thanks.